# Angular JS, AJAX calls on select to fill in another select

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Has anyone done anything with AngularJS and select droplists populating another droplist on the page based on a selection.

We have a service we are populating a Select droplist with. But we have another droplist on the page that, when the first droplist's section is made, the second droplist will dynamically populate with information based on the selection of the first droplist.

JSON structure example:

```
[{
   "Cars":{
     "Type": "Hatchback",
     "Type": "Sedan"
    },
   "Trucks":{
     "Type": "Small",
     "Type": "Full Size"
    }
}]
```

So if my first `<select>` droplist contains options for Cars and Trucks, then based on that selection the second `<select>`droplist will dynamically populate with the 'Type' based on the selection of a Car or Truck.

Does anyone have any insight or point me to any tutorials based on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up ng-repeat and ng-show. What you could do is hide the second drop down until the user picks something from the first. When they do based on that selection pull part of your object array into the ng-repeat and populate the second drop down.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option in you first selection to populate the list:

```
<select ng-model="d1" ng-options="key for key in vehKeys"></select>
<select ng-model="d2" ng-options="t.Type for t in veh[d1]"></select>
```

my controller looks like this:(I changed your format, as it was, Type would just keep overwriting its self)

```
$scope.veh = {
   "Cars":[
     {"Type": "Hatchback"},
     {"Type": "Sedan"}
    ],
   "Trucks":[
     {"Type": "Small"},
     {"Type": "Full Size"}
    ]
};

$scope.vehKeys = Object.keys($scope.veh);
```

I'm not entirely sure why you cannot do something like this though

```
<select ng-model="d1" ng-options="type for type in Object.keys(veh)"></select>
```

so I just did it in the controller.